# Calculate specific control occurance in a winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, tabs, textbox

A winform contains multiple textboxes placed in panels and panels are placed in tab pages of tab control. So, what I want is that can I calculate the number of textbox controls in that winform and how can I access the all textboxes.

Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You want to do this at runtime? Or based on the source code? If the former, you can recursively search the loaded form's control tree. If the latter, shouldn't "ctrl-F" suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty piece of code demonstrating how to recursively iterate through all the controls on a form. It is recursive, meaning it'll dig down through other container controls.

```
    ' create a list of textboxes
    Dim allTextBoxes As New List(Of TextBox)

    ' call a recursive finction to get a list of all the textboxes
    ExamineControls(allTextBoxes, Me.Controls)

    ' run through the list and look at them
    For Each t As TextBox In allTextBoxes
        Debug.Print(t.Name)
    Next



Private Sub ExamineControls(allTextBoxes As List(Of TextBox), controlCollection As Control.ControlCollection)
    For Each c As Control In controlCollection
        If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
            ' it's a textbox, add it to the collection
            allTextBoxes.Add(c)
        ElseIf c.Controls IsNot Nothing AndAlso c.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            ' it's some kind of container, recurse
            ExamineControls(allTextBoxes, c.Controls)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You'll obviously want to move this logic into a different part of your form and store the results in a form level list of type textbox...